# Beam: ReadAllFromText receive string or list from DoFn different behavior?

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have one pipeline read file from `GCS` through `Pub\Sub`,

```py
class ExtractFileNameFn(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        file_name = 'gs://' + "/".join(element['id'].split("/")[:-1])
        logging.info("Load file: " + file_name)
        yield file_name

class LogFn(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        logging.info(element)
        return [element]

class LogPassThroughFn(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        logging.info(element)
        return element

...

    p
    | "Read Sub Message" >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(topic=args.topic)
    | "Convert Message to JSON" >> beam.Map(lambda message: json.loads(message))
    | "Extract File Name" >> beam.ParDo(ExtractFileNameFn())
    | 'Log Results' >> beam.ParDo(LogFn())
    # | 'Log Results' >> beam.ParDo(LogPassThroughFn())
    | "Read File from GCS" >> beam.io.ReadAllFromText()
```

The difference of `LogPassThroughFn` and `LogPassThroughFn` is the type of return value, one the `string`, the other is `list`. And the `LogFn` works well in test codes, but `LogPassThroughFn` make the pipeline failed to run. Per [this issue answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53949842/3011380)

> Beam Python SDK still tries to interpret the output of that ParDo as if it was a collection of elements. And it does so by interpreting the string you emitted as collection of characters.

We know `LogFn` should work correctly.

However, I notice the `ExtractFileNameFn` return `string` rather than `list`. Is that correct? Then I test it as below, return `list` in `ExtractFileNameFn1`

```py
class ExtractFileNameFn1(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        file_name = 'gs://' + "/".join(element['id'].split("/")[:-1])
        logging.info("Load file: " + file_name)
        yield [file_name]

...

    p
    | "Read Sub Message" >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(topic=args.topic)
    | "Convert Message to JSON" >> beam.Map(lambda message: json.loads(message))
    | "Extract File Name" >> beam.ParDo(ExtractFileNameFn1())
    | "Read File from GCS" >> beam.io.ReadAllFromText()
```

Now, the pipeline failed to run...

My question is What the difference between return `string` and return `list` in DoFn? Why `ReadAllFromText` could receive `string` from `ExtractFileNameFn`, but receive `list` from `LogFn`?

beam version: 2.14.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs for `ParDo` say that:

> Note that the DoFn must return an iterable for each element of the input PCollection. An easy way to do this is to use the yield keyword in the process method.

https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.6.0/apache_beam.transforms.core.html#apache_beam.transforms.core.ParDo

The purpose of returning an iterable is that your input elements may not map 1-1 with your output elements. A single input may produce multiple outputs.

you are able to `yield` them as you go, or you can gather them up into a list and `return` them at the end

So this:

```
class ExtractFileNameFn(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        file_name = 'gs://' + "/".join(element['id'].split("/")[:-1])
        logging.info("Load file: " + file_name)
        yield file_name
```

would be the same as this:

```
class ExtractFileNameFn(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        file_name = 'gs://' + "/".join(element['id'].split("/")[:-1])
        logging.info("Load file: " + file_name)
        return [file_name]
```

the output elements for both are strings, each output element being a filename

When you do `yield [file_name]`, each output element is actually a list containing a string